# prevent CSS overwritten by site stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know there're some threads regarding the following issue but I didn't find anyone that suits me.

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that creates a dynamic table inside a div.
The div fills the whole window and the table is being position at the top right corner. Another important thing - the table is draggable. Till here all is good.

Unfortunately on some sites the tables ui looks a bit different due to css overwritten.

Most of the solutions suggest the use of iframe, now because of the drag-and-drop and that iframe consume all the mouse events I cannot use them.

Any other suggestion would be great!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Googling reveals [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)